# Angular 2 Karma - Running a test without simplifying the source code for debug purpose

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

As the title of this post suggests i want to be able to debug the source code of my angular project. After starting the test with the command **ng test** i'm trying to debug the code in Chrome. The code for the test case is completely fine, but the code of the service i'm testing has been obfuscated and simplified.

How can i disable the obfuscation and the simplification when trying to debug a test case in karma?